# Delete API call in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My method:

```
 deleteSample = () => {
        this.sampleService
          .deleteCall(this.props.id)
          .then((response) => {
             window.location.reload(false);
            })

          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      };
```

Service Class:

```
 deleteCall(id: string): Promise<{}> {
    const URL = `${this.ENDPOINT}/${id}`;
    return http
      .delete(apiURL)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

Component:

```
<Button onClick={this.deleteSample}
            >
              Delete
            </Button>
```

On click of button, I want to delete the item. Deleting is working but only after refreshing the page.I dont want to use  **window.location.reload(false);** to refresh the page but want to delete the item without refreshing. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: You need to provide some more code showing how you render your element which you are deleting, and where you store your data for that element.

Comment: i am showing the list of cards. and in a card there is a button called delete, which deletes that particular card. I am able to delete the card, but deletion from the screen happens only when the page is refreshed. But I dont want the page to get refreshed, but meanwhile delete should also work

Comment: @Singh, you can take remaining records as a response of delete Api and then rebind the data.

Comment: it would be great if you can tell me how to do that? @Khabir

Comment: @Singh, I cannot show you any api for delete that sends back the remaining record as response but I prepared an example and posted  as answer. Please check that, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared one example. Here I call delete api and after getting the response, I removed that deleted item from the list.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPage() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return function cleanup() {
            isSubscribed = false;
            signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        }
    }, []);

    function deletePost(postId){
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + postId, {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res , 'res');
                setPost(posts.filter(p => p.id !== postId));
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <div><span key={post.id}>{post.title}</span> <button onClick={() => deletePost(post.id)}>Delete</button></div>)
                }
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default PostListPage;
```